# Flexbox css3 make a responsive centred row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, responsiveness

> I have a 3 box example here all horizontally centered and trying to make them responsive, so if the resolution drops they will stack.  I've tried doing this with flex box because it allows any box to grow and still lines up.  Originally I put the boxes in bootstrap 3 row with the cols-lg (md etc) set but it would never unstack them!  The outer wrapper (.wpr) will on implementation be a banner which is why I would like the positional boxes horizontally aligned where possible.

Note: The answer doesn't have to use flexbox!

[image: Full width]

[image: Reduced Screen]

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vko41d5L/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wpr">
    <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">A B C</div> 
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue;">2</div>   
    <div class="box" style="background-color: pink;">3</div>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wpr
{
    width: 100%;    
    background: grey;
    padding: 10px 30px;    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: top; /* align vertical */    
}

div.box 
{
    width: 200px;    
    min-width: 200px;    
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 72px;    
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.wpr` as seen in my [demo](http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/oZxxgQ?editors=0100).

Comment: perfect, can't believe I overlooked that, I'm sure I'll not be the last!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the `flex-wrap: wrap;` property to the `.wpr` class.

```
.wpr
{
    width: 100%;    
    background: grey;
    padding: 10px 30px;    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: top; /* align vertical */    
    flex-wrap: wrap;  <===
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h4h75mnn/

Check out this Pen @ Codepen to play around with flexbox: http://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv/